# Access to protected . What differencies which link use(parent or child)?

Tags: java, scope

Please help me with this issue:

consider this code

```
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

public class MyObservable extends Observable {
    int k;
    public int getK() {
        return k;
    }

    public void setK(int k) {
        this.k = k;
        setChanged();   //valid
    }

    public static  void   main(String [] args){
        Observable observable = new MyObservable();

        Observer myObserver1 = new MyObserver();
        Observer myObserver2 = new MyObserver();

        observable.addObserver(myObserver1);
        observable.addObserver(myObserver2);

        observable.setChanged(); //compilation error here
        observable.notifyObservers();
    }
}
```

I invoke  `setChanged()` from public method(it is valid) and from public static method(it is not valid(I see message that it is protected method and it is not vald)). I thought that static/non static has not affect to access.

I cannot understand why.

I'm waiting for your right explanation.

I want to know why java founders Do made it so? What are conceptually wrong in my variant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not *really* a static/non-static difference - it's a difference in the compile-time type of the reference you're trying to call the method on.

In the instance method, you're implicitly calling it on `this`, which has a compile-time type of `MyObservable`. In `main`, you're calling it on a reference of type `Observable`, and you can't do that because of how `protected` access works.

From the JLS, [section 6.6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2) (emphasis near the end is mine):

> A protected member or constructor of an object may be accessed from outside the package in which it is declared only by code that is responsible for the implementation of that object.
>
> **6.6.2.1. Access to a protected Member**
>
> Let C be the class in which a protected member is declared. Access is permitted only within the body of a subclass S of C.
>
> In addition, if Id denotes an instance field or instance method, then:
>
> - If the access is by a qualified name Q.Id, where Q is an ExpressionName, then the access is permitted **if and only if the type of the expression Q is S or a subclass of S**.
> - If the access is by a field access expression E.Id, where E is a Primary expression, or by a method invocation expression E.Id(. . .), where E is a Primary expression, then the access is permitted if and only if the type of E is S or a subclass of S.

So in this case, if you change the declared type of `observable` to `MyObservable`, you'll find the error goes away.

Comment: What are these concepts? why it was made?

Comment: @gstackoverflow: I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: Sorry for bad english.  I don't understand conceptual cause to  
forbid this construction?

Comment: @gstackoverflow: The idea is that classes should only be able to use protected members of instances of their own class... A sort of 'bit less than totally private' feeling.

Comment: I know it)  What bad if permit to use *observable.setChanged()*?  if put Observable and MyObservable to one package - it would works

Comment: @gstackoverflow: It would allow you to call `setChanged()` on *any* instance of `Observable`, even ones that your class isn't "responsible" for - that's what we're trying to avoid. As for the package part - that's because protected members are *also* accessible to any class in the same package. (So it's slightly more public than the default package access.)

Comment: my variant to permit invocation from chain of inheritance and to forbid in another places. Why is not it possible to realize?

Comment: @gstackoverflow: I don't follow what you mean - but basically you don't get to decide the Java language's approach to access control. That's done and fixed. If you're trying to get "protected but without package access" that's just not supported.